# Using foreach & splice to replace 2 or more elements in an array

Tags: perl, foreach, indexing

```
@array = {....,.....,...., "keyword1", ....., ..... "keyword2, ....., ....);

foreach my $item(@array)
{

  if ($item =~ /keyword1/)
  {
    splice @array, $count, 0, "word1", "word2", "word3";
  }

  elsif ($item =~ /keyword2/)
  {
   splice @array, $count, 0, "word4";
  }
 $count++;
}
```

I am trying to modify an existing array by replacing 2 keywords with new strings using a foreach loop, but i read that perl has some issues with indexing while the array is being spliced.  What is an alternative/better way to implement this logic?

Comment: Don't modify the array over which you are iteration using a foreach loop.

Comment: This code isn't even close to compile-able Perl. What are you *actually* doing? What does your real code look like?

Comment: The syntax highlighting should tip you off that you have some unterminated construct at the beginning. Namely, you open your literal array with a `{` instead of a `(`.

Answer (score 2):

You iterate over the indexes through `$count` (which isn't a count but an index), but you don't actually use it when it comes to to see if it's time to stop looping!

Normally, when you want to iterate over the indexes, you'd use

```
for my $i (0..$#a) {
   ... $a[$i] ...
}
```

But that won't work here since you mess around with the indexes of the elements of the array. You could a `while` loop , as in the following code: (A C-style for loop is just a fancy `while` loop.)

```
for (my $i=0; $i<@a; ++$i) {
   if ($a[$i] =~ /keyword1/) {
      splice @a, $i, 0, qw( word1 word2 word3 );
      $i += 3;
   }
   elsif ($a[$i] =~ /keyword2/) {
      splice @a, $i, 0, "word4";
      $i += 1;
   }
}
```

In situations like this, it's easier to iterate backwards.

```
for (my $i=@a; $i--; ) {
   if ($a[$i] =~ /keyword1/) {
      splice @a, $i, 0, qw( word1 word2 word3 );
   }
   elsif ($a[$i] =~ /keyword2/) {
      splice @a, $i, 0, "word4";
   }
}
```

`map` is used to translate one list into another, so it could also be used here. With `map`, you don't have to worry about changing the index variable by an incorrect amount.

```
@a = map {
   if    (/keyword1/) { qw( word1 word2 word3 ), $_  }
   elsif (/keyword2/) { 'word4', $_                  }
   else               { $_                           }
} @a;
```

Comment: err, the splices won't copy any scalar, much less all of them.

Comment: Why get rid of the `map` solution?  In my opinion, it's the easiest method not to mess up, and also the easiest the read.  Definitely two good reasons to just go with that.

Comment: @Miller, To save me from writing a new intro text. Reintroduced. I even formatted the block's contents better.

Comment: Ahhh, much better, ty.  I'm sure there are times when [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) really is the right tool for the job, but I must admit I use it so rarely that it takes me a second to decypher where the last [`for`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/for.html) solution is inserting the new elements.  Alternatively, using [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) feels much less fragile, and one can see at a glance where new entries are being inserted, namely before the found keywords.

Comment: Btw, I know that `for my $i (0.10)` is handled efficiently by perl as an incrementor without the need to create an 11 element array.  However, I have a vague memory of a thread on perlmonks for 4-5 years ago, that the following `for my $i (reverse 0..10)` is also efficiently turned into a simple decrementor by the perl interpreter `for (my $i = 0; $i <=10; $i--)`.  Am I dreaming that?

Comment: @Miller, appears you were dreaming that, from comparing output of `perl -MO=Concise,-exec -we'for (reverse 1..10) {}'`, `perl -MO=Concise,-exec -we'for (1..10) {}'`  An array is generated from 1..10 and then it loops over that in reverse.

Comment: @ysth Thanks mate.  I wish I had the specific education to be able to read the output of [`Concise`](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Concise.html), as it might as well be Klingon to me.

Comment: @Miller, In `for (reverse LIST)`, the `reverse` is optimized away and replaced with a flag that tells the foreach to go backwards. But the list is still flattened even if it's a range. (It's flattened at compile-time, it's a constant range!)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here:

When you use a `for` loop over an array, each item is an *alias* of the item in the array:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

my @array = qw(zero one two three four five);

for my $value ( @array ) {
    if ( $value eq "four" ) {
        $value = "SURPIRSE!";
    }
}

say join ": ", @array;
```

This prints out "`zero: one: two: three: SURPIRSE@!: five`"

Therefore, when you change items in your `for` loop, even if you're not using `$_`, you're still accessing that loop directly.

Adding items in the middle of an array while going through each time can cause problems. Also, you are using the variable `$count`, but never defined its initial value. Always include:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

in your scripts!

To do what you want, I would suggest you use two separate arrays and copy from the first array to the second. This will solve a lot of your issues.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

my @array = qw(zero one two keyword1 three four keyword2 five);
my @new_array;

for my $value ( @array ) {
    if ( $value eq "keyword1" ) {
        push @new_array, "word1", "word2", "word3";
    }
    elsif ( $value eq "keyword2" ) {
        push @new_array, "word3";
    }
    else {
        push @new_array, $value;
    }
}
say join ": ", @new_array;
```